# Faster way to parse a JSON String in android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I'm using this method to parse a JSON string, but it is too slow... is there a better way to do it?
Thanks

```
synchronized private void parseCategories(String response){

    try{
        JSONArray categoriesJSONArray = new JSONArray (response);


        // looping through All Contacts
        for(int i = 0; i < categoriesJSONArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject currentCategory = categoriesJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String label="";
            String categoryId="";


            // Storing each json item in variable
            if(currentCategory.has("label"))
                label = currentCategory.getString("label");


            if(currentCategory.has("id"))
                categoryId = currentCategory.getString("id");

            if(
               label!=null &&
               categoryId!=null
              )
            {
                Category toAdd = new Category(categoryId, label);
                categories.add(toAdd);
            }

        }

        //Alphabetic order
        Collections.sort(
                categories,
                new Comparator<Feed>() {
                    public int compare(Feed lhs, Feed rhs) {
                        return lhs.getTitle().compareTo(rhs.getTitle());
                    }
                }
        );

        Intent intent = new Intent("CategoriesLoaded");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mAppContext).sendBroadcast(intent);


    }catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using GSON? I am not sure if it is faster but it much more convinient

Comment: You are setting label="" and categoryId="" so there is no way they can be null. So don't you end up adding a lot of categories with "" as label and id?

Comment: None of the answer is fastest though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's try following code to start with. You would need `Gson` library for it.

```
Gson gson=new Gson();
MyBean myBean=gson.fromJson(response);
```

`Note:` Here MyBean class contains the fields present in you json string for e.g. `id`, along with getter and setters. Rest of all is handled by `Gson`.

Here's a quick demo.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Box {

  @SerializedName("id")
  private String categoryId;

  // getter and setter
}
```

Say you `JSON` looks as following:

```
{"id":"A12"}
```

You can parse it as follows:

```
class Parse{
 public void parseJson(String response){
  Gson gson=new Gson();
  Box box=gson.fromJson(response,Box.class);
  System.out.println(box.getCategoryId());
 }
}
```

**Output :**

```
A12
```

For more on `Gson` visit [here](http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/)

Comment: Thanks, but how Can I do if the parameter "id" in the json string must inserted in the String "id_cat" of the class... is there a way to do that?

Comment: Use annotations for them. You can specify json key in class's field annotation.

Comment: Thanks, It help. But I have a class called Feed and 2 others that inherits from it... Is there a way to create different annotation for the  subclasses?

Comment: Yes you can do that (provide different annotations)

Comment: Thanks, I can't find an example of different annotations. 
Can you post an example?
Feed has got the ID tag
Subscriptions ID tag must be for example id_sub
Categories ID tag must be for example id_cat

Comment: Apparently you cannot have multiple annotations for same field. You'll have to manage it logically.

Answer (score 1):

Use GSON library. You can convert your object to json string like the following example:

```
MyClass MyObject;
Gson gson = new Gson();
String strJson = gson.toJson(MyObject);
```